# How can I Pass Firebase Push Notification Token from AppDelegate : CDVAppDelegate to MainController.js file in iOS Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I am working on a Cordova based Application for both iOS and Android Platforms.
I need to pass the received Device Token using the Firebase Push Notification Delegate method From AppDelegate to My Project MainController.js file.

I am able to pass that in Android using the CookieManager.

```
   FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("Fetching FCM registration token failed");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get new FCM registration token
                    FCM_token = task.getResult();
                    CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    cm.setAcceptCookie(true);
                    cm.setCookie(launchUrl,FCM_token);

                    // Log and toast
                    // String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
                    System.out.println("DEVICE_TOKEN::"+FCM_token);
                    Log.d("DEVICE_TOKEN::",FCM_token);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

For iOS, I am trying to paas the device token using HTTPCookieStorage using the code

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:@{NSHTTPCookieName: @"MyCookie",
NSHTTPCookieValue: _deviceToken, //@"CookieValue",
NSHTTPCookieDomain: @"example.com",
NSHTTPCookiePath: configPath}];


// Store the cookie in the cookie storage
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

This Cookie is not getting transferred from AppDelegate to the .js file.

I tried with other options also,

```
 NSString * jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doSomething('%@');",url];
[self.viewController.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];
```

but this method is not getting triggered in .js file.
I don't want to use any additional plugin for this, as using the implementation for Android, I am able to receive the Push Notification.
I want to know how this can be done for iOS.?